# My Variable isn't changing after an elif statement says to do so

Tags: python

My code is supposed to take 1 off of num_of_guess but it keeps repeating at 11 guesses and not going down.

```
def guess():
        num_of_guess=12
        while num_of_guess>0:
            lines=open('five.txt').read().splitlines()
            myLine= random.choice(lines)
            list(myLine)
            guesses=input('Guess my five-letter word by guessing one number at a time.')
            if list(guesses) == myLine:
                print('You correctly guessed')
            else:
                num_of_guess-=1
                print('Try again.'+str(num_of_guess)+' guesses left!')
                guess()
        return num_of_guess
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use recursion (call of `guess` in the function `guess`) here. Overall there's too much wrong in this code (`list(myLine)` does nothing, `list(guesses) == myLine` doesn't do what you think, ...).

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- myLine is not a list, calling list(myLine) creates a new list but it isn't assigned anywhere.
- Instead of comparing list(guesses) to myLine, you can just compare guesses to myLine directly.
- you're already in a loop to handle guesses, so you don't need to call guess() within the else case. Otherwise you can keep guessing forever and your attempt counter won't matter.
- you should pick the random item to guess for before you enter the loop otherwise the string to pick will change on each iteration

From the output, it seems you are trying to compare the input one letter at a time, but you should be able to simply compare the full input to the item. If you want to compare one letter at a time, you can use list() to split the target string, and read the input one character at a time until it doesn't match.

Comment: Isn't the list() what you told me not to do.

Comment: @nathannotnathan No, he told you that `list(myLine)` achieves nothing. You transform `myLine` to a list and ignore the result. The call to `list` doesn't change `myLine`.